# Editing gitbook index.html

Tags: gitbook

How do I edit the main index.html generated by gitbook?

I imagine this is probably super simple, but I can't find where the index.html file is being created. Right now it only shows the message "Choose a language" with the languages available underneath, and I would like to add more information to it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer comes a little late, sorry.

The main `index.html` is generated from the `README.md` file in the main folder.

Comment: 13abylon, I might be mistaken, but that doesn't seem right. I'm referring especifically to the language picker index.html, like  the one [here](http://docs.azk.io/), I think you might be referring to this one [here](http://docs.azk.io/en/index.html)